# TensorFlow : Error building pip package

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build TensorFlow from source. After configuring the installation, when I try to build to the pip package with the following command,

`$ bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: /workspace/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1312:1: Executing genrule //tensorflow/core:version_info_gen failed: bash failed: error executing command
(cd /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/eab0d61a99b6696edb3d2aff87b585e8/execroot/workspace && \
exec env - \
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin \
/bin/bash -c 'source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py --generate tensorflow/tools/git/gen
/spec.json tensorflow/tools/git/gen/head tensorflow/tools/git/gen/branch_ref "bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/core/util/version_info.cc"'): com.goo
gle.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py", line 260, in <module>
generate(args.generate)
File "tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py", line 212, in generate
git_version = get_git_version(data["path"])
File "tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py", line 152, in get_git_version
str("--work-tree=" + git_base_path), "describe", "--long", "--tags"
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 8.567s, Critical Path: 7.90s
```

What's going wrong?

(Ubuntu 14.04, CPU only)

Answer (score 1):

Your build appears to be encountering an error in

```
tensorflow/tools/git/gen_git_source.py
```

at line 152. At this stage in the build the script is trying to get the git version number of your tensor flow repo. Have you used git to check out your tensor flow repo? Are the .git files present in the /tensorflow/ root dir? Maybe you need to update your version of git?

Looks similar to this question: [Build Error Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551440/error-when-trying-to-build-tensorflow)

Comment: Was running tensorflow inside a docker container, and it didn't had git. Installed git, and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error even though I had `git` in my `PATH` variable. I got a hint from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5659249/212076 that the launched subprocess was not getting the `PATH` variable.

The solution was to hard-code the `git` command in `<ROOT>\tensorflow\tensorflow\tools\git\gen_git_source.py` by replacing

```
val = bytes(subprocess.check_output([
        "git", str("--git-dir=%s/.git" % git_base_path),
        str("--work-tree=" + git_base_path), "describe", "--long", "--tags"
    ]).strip())
```

with

```
val = bytes(subprocess.check_output([
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.cmd", str("--git-dir=%s/.git" % git_base_path),
        str("--work-tree=" + git_base_path), "describe", "--long", "--tags"
    ]).strip())
```

Once this got fixed I got another error: `fatal: Not a git repository: './.git'`.
I figured the tensorflow root folder was the one that should have been referenced and so I edited `<ROOT>\tensorflow\tensorflow\tools\git\gen_git_source.py` to replace

```
git_version = get_git_version(".")
```

with

```
git_version = get_git_version("../../../../")
```

After that the build was successful.

NOTE: Unlike OP, my build platform was Windows 7 64 bit